# Not run through button´s action android

Tags: android

How can I put a transparent button upon SeekBar to make this seek bar not touchable. I have put the button but I can touch the SeekBar too. In the properties of the SeekBar I have put clickable=false and focusable=false. Is button´s some property to not run through the button´s click? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button.

Try this -

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

**EDIT**

Why don't you simply disable the seekbar -

```
mySeekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

or for XML:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, is more helpful than negative votes without reasons, but if I put SeekBar disabled I still can click on SeekBar